# Display name of minimum value in joined tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following tables:

```
      Projects                    Comparisons                Assets
ProjectID ProjectName    CompareID ProjectID AssetID    AssetID AssetName
    1          A           101        1       201         201      ZZZ
    2          B           102        1       202         202      YYY
    3          C           103        2       203         203      XXX
                           104        3       204         204      WWW
                           105        1       205         205      VVV
                           106        2       206         206      UUU
                           107        1       207         207      TTT
```

(Comparisons and Assets actually have additional information that necessitates them being separate tables even though this example makes it look like I could make it all one table.)

I have a form whose Record Source is Projects (meaning 3 entries) and I want to include a field that gives the AssetName corresponding to the lowest ComparisonID for the ProjectID.  Something like this:

```
ProjectName:  A    (Lowest CompareID is 101)    AssetName:  ZZZ
ProjectName:  B    (Lowest CompareID is 103)    AssetName:  XXX
ProjectName:  C    (Lowest CompareID is 104)    AssetName:  WWW
```

On my form, I've gotten as far as listing the Control Source as Projects.ProjectID and the Row Source as

```
SELECT Projects.ProjectID, Min(Comparisons.CompareID)
FROM Comparisons INNER JOIN Projects ON Comparisons.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID
GROUP BY Projects.ProjectID;
```

I cannot figure out how to incorporate Assets.  If I add Assets.AssetName to the SELECT line, then I need to include this field somewhere else in the command.  If it's part of the GROUP BY, then I end up with multiple entries per project which I don't want.  So now it's a bunch of trial and error that hasn't been successful.  Please help, smart people!!

Comment: Have you tried using your current query as a subquery to get records from Comparisons table first and then inner joining it with Assests?

Comment: Would love to see the SQL for this as I'm struggling to get it working without putting AssetID on SELECT line.

Comment: Can you check if the answer I mentioned below works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it worked out using Min on a string, which I didn't know was possible.

```
SELECT Projects.ProjectID, Min(Comparisons.CompareID), Min(Assets.AssetName)
FROM Assets INNER JOIN (Comparisons INNER JOIN Projects ON Comparisons.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID) ON Assets.AssetID = Comparisons.AssetID
GROUP BY Projects.ProjectID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write a subquery get `Min(CompareID)` and `MIN(AssetID)` from `Comparisons` table then `JOIN`.

```
SELECT Projects.ProjectName, 
       CompareIDMin,
       Assets.AssetName
FROM (
   select ProjectID,Min(CompareID) AS CompareIDMin,MIN(AssetID) AS AssetIDMin
   FROM Comparisons
   GROUP BY ProjectID
) as c
INNER JOIN Projects ON c.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID
INNER JOIN Assets ON Assets.AssetID = c.AssetIDMin
```

Here is an sql-server sample but I think it can work in access,

[SQLFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d536f86e8edc4a54114817b7cbbcd49d)

Comment: I've tried this.  As I stated, this gives me multiple entries per project, one for each AssetName.

Comment: Here's my code so you can check for typos:<br/>    SELECT Projects.ProjectName, CompareIDMin, Assets.AssetName<br/>
    FROM (SELECT ProjectID, Min(CompareID) AS CompareIDMin, MIN(AssetID) AS AssetIDMin FROM Comparisons GROUP BY ProjectID) as c<br/>    
INNER JOIN Projects ON c.ProjectID = Projects.ProjectID<br/>    
INNER JOIN Assets ON Assets.AssetID = c.AssetIDMin<br/>It gives a syntax error (missing operator) c.ProjectID=Projects.ProjectID INNER JOIN Assets ON Assets.AssetID=c.AssetIDMi

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? Instead of joining you may also be able to use it as a subquery in WHERE clause which might be a better alternative.

```
SELECT C.ProjectID, C.CompareID, C.AssetID
FROM Comparisons C 
JOIN (SELECT ProjectID, Min(CompareID) as CompareID FROM Comparisons GROUP BY ProjectID) S
ON C.ProjectID = S.ProjectID and C.CompareID = S.CompareID
```

Comment: Syntax error in FROM clause - highlights JOIN (I think I need to use an INNER/LEFT/RIGHT JOIN)

Comment: Try INNER JOIN then. JOIN and INNER JOIN is the same thing.